# What is the file type "raw G3 data, byte-padded"

Tags: files

I ran

```
$ find ~/ |xargs file|grep -i -e SQLite
```

just to understand what programs use sqlite. I started seeing lines like

```
/home/alord/hg/cpython/.hg/store/data/_modules/__sqlite/cursor.c.i: raw G3 data, byte-padded
```

What is G3 Data?

Answer (score 4):

The magic database on Linux declares the type “raw G3 data” for files starting with the two byte values 0, 20, and “raw G3 data, byte-padded” for files starting with the two byte values 0, 1. As you can see, this is very broad and has a lot of potential for false positives. “G3 data” refers to [group 3 faxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fax#Digital), which most people are unlikely to encounter in this century.

The binary format that Mercurial uses to store information about a file in a working copy is prone to having files that happen to start with the two bytes 0, 1. It isn't the only one.